# Regarding SQL Queries (Updating Records)

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, vba

I have a program that will cater to an employee's leave application. So far everything is running smoothly except for this block of code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblEmployee " & _
                        " SET EMP_PATERNITYCRED=" & Me.txtNumDays.Text & _
                        ", EMP_LOGINDT='" & Me.dateToday.Value.Date & "'" & _
                        ", [Reason for Leave]='" & Me.txtReason.Text & "'" & _
                        " WHERE EMP_LNAME=" & lblLastName.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This code block's intention is to update a record from `tblEmployee` of the database, with the following columns listed down. The error points to the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, and it says `No value given for one or more required parameters`.

I personally think that it's the column named `Reason for Leave`, since it has spaces instead of underscores. What do you think?

Thank you for those who will help me!

Comment: You are missing single quotes in the `where` clause for the last name.

Comment: Oh, right!! I just noticed it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try backquotes?

```
", `Reason for Leave` = '" & Me.txtReason.Text & "'" &_
```

I am little surprised that [] doesn't work in mysql.

Comment: I was also surprised because [] is used in the query builder, right? But thanks! I will try this out too. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

For your own sanity, leverage the String.Format() function:

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE tblEmployee SET EMP_PATERNITYCRED = {0}, EMP_LOGINDT = '{1}', [Reason for Leave] = '{2}' WHERE EMP_LNAME = '{3}'"

sql = String.Format(sql, Me.txtNumDays.Text, Me.dateToday.Value.Date, Me.txtReason.Text, lblLastName.Text)
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This makes the missing single-quotes in your OP evident.